# webpack-cli Error: Unknown option '--no-progress'

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, material-ui, laravel-6

I am facing some errors during refactoring an old project. also, this project is upgraded from laravel 5.8 to 6.0 laravel. but most likely it is failing during npm run prod. I wonder what is happening. just before the upgrade it was fine.

```
[webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--no-progress'
[webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/w                         ebpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/w                         ebpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ production script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log                         ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2021-05-27T12_01_52_782Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ prod: `npm run production`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log                         ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2021-05-27T12_01_52_797Z-debug.log
```

so my package .json will look like this:

````
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"resolutions": {
    "minimist": "^1.2.5"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.58",
    "@mdi/font": "^4.9.95",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^1.6.16",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@trendmicro/react-sidenav": "^0.5.0",
    "@vue/cli": "^4.5.13",
    "braces": "^2.3.2",
    "canvasjs": "^1.8.3",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^8.6.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^5.0.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.36",
    "material-ui-password-field": "^2.1.2",
    "mdbvue": "^6.7.2",
    "module": "^1.2.5",
    "msg91": "0.0.6",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "pondjs": "^0.9.0",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.0.4",
    "react-custom-radio": "^1.0.7",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.9",
    "react-google-charts": "^3.0.15",
    "react-move": "^6.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.7.0",
    "react-pdf": "^4.2.0",
    "react-progressbar": "^15.4.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-signature-canvas": "^1.0.3",
    "react-simple-dropdown": "^3.2.3",
    "react-timeseries-charts": "^0.16.1",
    "react-toastify": "^5.5.0",
    "react-vis": "^1.11.7",
    "recharts": "^2.0.9",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-awesome-swiper": "^4.1.1",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.5",
    "vue-chartist": "^2.3.1",
    "vue-ckeditor2": "^2.1.5",
    "vue-click-outside": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-custom-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "vue-easy-slider": "^5.3.4",
    "vue-event-hub": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-kanban": "^1.8.0",
    "vue-loader": "^16.2.0",
    "vue-picture-input": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-plyr": "^5.1.3",
    "vue-resizable": "^1.3.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
    "vue-smooth-dnd": "^0.8.0",
    "vue-split-panel": "^1.0.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-video": "^0.1.7",
    "vue2-editor": "^2.10.2",
    "vueditor": "^0.3.1",
    "vuescroll": "^4.17.3",
    "vuetify-media-player": "^0.8.1",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2",
    "watch": "^1.0.2",
    "write-json-file": "^4.3.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.13",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.19",
    "minimist": "^1.2.5",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "pug-loader": "^2.4.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.34.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.8",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.6.3",
    "vuetify": "^2.5.1",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.2",
    "webpack": "^5.37.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.0"
},
"eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:vue/essential",
        "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": 0,
        "no-irregular-whitespace": 0
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
},
"postcss": {
    "plugins": {
        "autoprefixer": []
    }
},
"browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
],
"description": "## Project setup ``` npm install ```",
"main": "babel.config.js",
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC"
````

}

my webpack.mix.js

```
    const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.pug$/,
            oneOf: [{
                    resourceQuery: /^\?vue/,
                    use: ['pug-plain-loader']
                },
                {
                    use: ['raw-loader', 'pug-plain-loader']
                },
                {
                    // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
                    // it's runtime that would otherwise processed through "file" loader.
                    // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
                    // by webpacks internal loaders.
                    exclude: [/\.js$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/, /\.ejs$/],
                    loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
                    options: {
                        name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
                    }
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
});
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

thanks in advance
looking for some valuable suggestions

Comment: Laravel removes some options. So you will need to update the scripts section of your package.json file accordingly. Follow this link https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/upgrade#update-your-npm-scripts

Comment: @VaibhavGidde it's actually not very clear to me as it's just a documentation link. I would love to have a little more specific answer. it is not an easy upgrade for laravel versions from lower to current or lravel8.

Comment: First try to update your npm scripts in the package.json file. It may resolve your build errors like unknown options or unknown arguments.

`"scripts": {
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "production": "mix --production"
}`